# Is the Samsung M2825DW Ubuntu friendly?

Tags: printing, samsung

Does anyone have any experience using the above printer in Ubuntu? Going by the long list of compatible Samsung printers on Ubuntu's website, I'm sure it's a fairly safe bet, but if anyone can confirm this I'd appreciate it.

*Edit* I'm not sure how to answer my own question, but having bought and installed the printer with no problems at all, I can say that yes, it is Ubuntu friendly.

Answer (score 1):

I use an old Samsung laser printer myself and it works fine. When I first got it, there was not a specific driver for it available. In cases like this you can generally use the "next nearest" model's driver with little or no loss in functionality.

If the printer understands PostScript, you can use the printer with a generic PostScript driver if you only print structured documents instead of bitmap images or the like.

Depending on what country you are in, local consumer law may also allow you to buy the printer and then return it if it is "not fit for purpose", but this is of course inconvenient and not really fair on the vendor either.

Also have a gander at openprinting.org and see if there's any info on your model.

Comment: OpenPrinting.org doesn't list the model number exactly, but everything of a similar model number seems to work perfectly, and I'll assume that that's a good sign.